# generate a batch(.bat) file using javascript or html

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file

Can I make a .bat file using html or javascript so the .the bat file will start to download.

I have alredy try

```
<a href="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,echo Hello echo world" download="hello-world.bat">clicking here</a>
```

Well this create a .bat file but between `echo Hello` and `echo world` I need a new line to make the .bat file correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) `\n` caracters to your `.bat` source string, [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) it to [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and set the `href` property of the `<a>` tag using javascript :

```
<a href="#" download="hello-world.bat">click here</a>
<script>
  var bat_source = "echo Hello\necho world";
  document.querySelector("a").href = 'data:text/plain;base64,' + btoa(bat_source);
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eo2ehj42/)

Comment: I think you meant `data:text/plain`.  Actually, there's no IANA registered MIME type for batch files, so `application/x-bat` would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you; and as rojo said i had to use text/plain otherwise it didn't work; Thanks again